# In Java is there a data types for data types?

Tags: java, variables, methods, types

I would like to pass a data type into a method but I can’t seem to find a data type for data types, I’m not sure what to do

Edit:
So when I refer to data type I refer to the part before declaring a variable, for example: int myNumber;

I would like to pass the type, so the method could take string or int and recognise it as the data type rather than a string, instead of using switch cases for each primitive data type

I will use the method to keep validating inputs, instead of try, except

Basically, I’m asking what the following underscore is:

_____ variable1 = String;

variable1 variable2 = “Words”;

And if there is a way to take a generic input using a scanner rather than specifying a data type, or to specify the data type using variable1

Comment: Please elaborate on how you define "data type" and what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a data type?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Answer (score 2):

I have in mind three solution for your problem, because I don't know exactly what you want.

**1.Object**

This is the data type that can accept and sustain any data type(that is an instance of a class). However, using this, you won't be able to use your personal methods written in your class(just overriding ones that are specific to Object class).

**2.Class**

As Mureinik already answered, java.lang.Class is an Object that contains information about your class at run-time, meaning that you can get for example the name of your class and others useful things(look in documentation)

**3.Generics**

Want to create a Class that supports different kind of object? Generics are your solution. Via generic classes, you can create different methods that will work for different kind of object(for example, the ones extended from *Number*)

Comment: So when I refer to data type I refer to the part before declaring a variable, for example: int myNumber;

Comment: @Llione So you want to pass `int.class`?

Comment: I would like to pass the generic type, so the method could take string or int and recognise it as the data type rather than a string

Comment: @Llione I suggest editing your question to add a [mre] of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can combine generic and Class class to find out about your type. Create a generic class and in a method, use Class. Suppose generic type var is T, you can do T.getClass() to get your class.